# on press button not working react native

Tags: react-native

I don't know why i can't access the onButtonPress function!,
I put warns to debug the code but it never enters the function session. 
I am following the complete react native and redux course for stephen grider but somehow this code doesn't work for me.

```
 <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
       Log in!
 </Button>

onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    console.warn('Pressed');
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(() => {
      console.warn('new authentication');
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catc`enter code here`h(() => {
        console.warn('error auth');
        this.setState({ error: 'Authentication Failed.' });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: If my answer below helps please mark it as the correct answer to this question. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I did the same course a while back. Your button needs to be in a return:

```
renderButton() {
  //Show the loading spinner if loading is true
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return <Spinner size="small" />;
  }

  //Otherwise show the log in button
  return (
    <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
      Log in
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Then you call renderButton within your jsx.
Let me know if this helps!

Comment: have the same problem! but this is the right soure code at stephen's github account but this is not working for me!